# Attribute 'directory' is not allowed to appear in element 'int:inbound-channel-adapter'

Tags: spring-integration

I'm new to Spring Integration and I'm trying to implement `file:inbound-channel-adapter`. The following error message keeps appearing:

> Line 18 in XML document from class path resource [spring-context.xml]
>   is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;
>   lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 82; cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute
>   'directory' is not allowed to appear in element
>   'int:inbound-channel-adapter'.

Does anyone know what this error means?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We're glad to have you :)  A couple of tips; you can format things like code and error messages (see my edit) to make your post more readable.  In addition, posting a code sample showing what you've tried would be extremely helpful.  Finally, and because I know that others will ask this as well, have you done a search for that error and read through the results?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it an issue of your code?

You ask for `file:inbound-channel-adapter`, but StackTrace says:

> int:inbound-channel-adapter